# care-o-bot spins in place with move command

Tags: ros, python, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know why the care-o-bot will sit in place and rotate about the z axis with some move commands.  For example:

self.sss.move("base","order");

From a startup state, the above command in a python script will cause the bot to spin in place.  I'm running ubuntu 10.4 with electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11434/care-o-bot-spins-in-place-with-move-command/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What kind of navigation are you using? I assume you are using "roslaunch cob_2dnav 2dnav.launch", which is the ROS navigation. Sounds like the robot in not properly localized. Please check the localization in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [fmw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1175/fmw/) with karma: 26 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-10-06**:
Oh - and yes, I'm using "roslaunch cob2dnav 2dnav.launch"

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-10-06**:
Thanks fmw.  Pardon the newbie question... but is it required that I run care-o-bot in rviz?  In working through the tutorials, I was under the impression that I could apply navigation goals (by python script) in gazebo.  What exactly does rviz add that I cannot do in gazebo?  I'd appreciate any comments you have - I'm new at this.